# Error al ejecutar un cursor con FORALL en tablas remotas oracle 19c

Tags: plsql, cursor

Tengo un error al ejecutar un cursor con `FORALL` en tablas remotas `Oracle 19c`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SOPORTEDBA.prc_del_ipm
IS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        CURSOR c1 IS
            SELECT ID_CONSUMO
              FROM PROD_ENTIDAD701.CONSUMOS@PRUEBAS701 C
             WHERE TRUNC (C.FECHA_CIERRE_COMERCIO) <
                   TRUNC (SYSDATE - INTERVAL '2' YEAR);

        TYPE t_id IS TABLE OF PROD_ENTIDAD701.IPM.ID_CONSUMO@PRUEBAS701%TYPE;

        l_id   t_id;
    BEGIN
        OPEN c1;

        LOOP
            FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO l_id LIMIT 100;

            EXIT WHEN l_id.COUNT = 0;

            FORALL i IN l_id.FIRST .. l_id.LAST
                DELETE FROM PROD_ENTIDAD701.IPM@PRUEBAS701
                      WHERE ID_CONSUMO = l_id (i);

            COMMIT;
        END LOOP;

        CLOSE c1;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: Y el error es...? Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.